# What is the meaning of the Chinese word translated to English as "sincerity"

Tags: mainland-china

Particularly, in the context of morality and citizenship. I am working on a project on China's proposed social credit system, and the term "sincerity" comes up frequently as a desired social good.

One example

> Strengthen **sincerity** management and education among civil servants. Establish civil servant **sincerity** dossiers, enter civil servants’ personal credit information concerning reports on events, records of **sincerity** and cleanliness in government aairs, the results of annual evaluations, acts violating laws, disciplines and contract into their les, and make civil servants’ **sincerity** records into an important basis for assessment, employment and rewards. Deeply launch education concerning **sincerity**, abiding by the law and morality among civil servants, strengthen study of legal knowledge and credit knowledge, compile civil servants’ **sincerity** manuals, strengthen the legal and **sincerity** consciousness of civil servants, establish a line of civil servant teams that abide by the law and by **sincerity**, are highly efficient and clean.

Comment: I do agree it sounds particularly strange coming from a Western perspective. _Integrity_ would be the desired attribute here in most Western contexts, although I'm not sure it captures the _earnestness_ and indeed _purity of heart_ required by the Chinese equivalent of _sincerity_.

Comment: @Michaelyus I think it should be "honesty"

Answer (score 1):

The original word for the English translation sincerity is: **诚信**.

---

I believe this is the exact original text from the English you quoted above:

> 加强公务员诚信管理和教育。建立公务员诚信档案，依法依规将公务员个人有关事项报告、廉政记录、年度考核结果、相关违法违纪违约行为等信用信息纳入档案，将公务员诚信记录作为干部考核、任用和奖惩的重要依据。深入开展公务员诚信、守法和道德教育，加强法律知识和信用知识学习，编制公务员诚信手册，增强公务员法律和诚信意识，建立一支守法守信、高效廉洁的公务员队伍。

---

Sincerity records are known as: [诚信档案](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%AF%9A%E4%BF%A1%E6%A1%A3%E6%A1%88/7194893).

---

[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=2&wdqt=%E8%AF%9A%E4%BF%A1%0D%0A) defines this as:

> genuine / honest / in good faith / honesty / integrity

Comment: 诚信 = 诚实守信 = honesty and trustworthiness